# Sqlite3 support for CTE and WITH clause on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, sqlite, common-table-expression, pythonanywhere

I've just deployed my project on pythonanywhere.com. I'm using Django 1.10.4 with sqlite3 as database. I've used some raw queries inside my application which make use of CTE and WITH clause. Sqlite3 supports them from version 3.8.3 (see [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)), unfortunately on pythonanywhere the available version of sqlite3 is 3.8.2.
Do any of you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: 1) Don't use PythonAnywhere, or 2) don't use CTEs.

Comment: I see you have an extremely high reputation, but... are you serious or just joking? Those suggestions are more of an (obvious) workaround other than a solution. Have you already encountered the same problem or something like that and you gave up? Do you suggest some alternative hosting service?

Comment: CTEs were added to SQLite because recursion is not otherwise possible in SQL alone. And you, as a mere user, have no control over the configuration of PythonAnywhere, which is the whole point of a hosting service. So your question's constraints make a solution impossible.

Comment: you can also try to compile the newer version of sqlite3 yourself and use that. (pythonanywhere has the gcc compiler)

Comment: It's the strategy I'm following. So far I've managed to compile a shared object library for sqlite3. I need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, so that python finds my library. I've managed to do that inside my bash shell, but not when the web application is reloaded. I've set the variable inside postactivate hook of virtualenvwrapper, but it seems to be ignored by the python instance which runs the server. According to https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps I should set it inside wsgi.py but set it at runtime is too late!